# Getting response data as "Authentication credentials were not provided" in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to automate one scenario after logging in. I have created one HTTP request for login and another for to do the action which is my scenario. For first HTTP request it is working fine and I'm able to login to application, when coming to second HTTP request it is showing response as "Authentication credentials were not provided". Please provide some reference.

Comment: Do you have cookie manager added to test plan?

Comment: As the application not using any cookies, I think there is no need?

Comment: Even I tried with that, but it is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After login to the application an API token will be generated. We need to use that for any further actions. So After login to your application look into response data and Verify the authentication token. Keep Regrex Extractor and copy that API Token and keep it in Request data. 
Let me know if you have any queries.